# echo multi-line string to a file

Tags: echo

How can I create a .gitignore file and add:

```
/node_modules
.DS_Store
.env
```

all in one command line?

I know I can do this: `echo ".DS_Store" >> .gitignore`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classic way to do this is using a HEREDOC (see `man bash`)

```
cat - <<EOF >> .gitignore
/nodemodules
.DS_Store
.env
EOF
```

Answer (score 1):

```sh
echo "
/node_modules
.DS_Store
.env" >> .gitignore
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually use printf, which allows me to write a oneliner:

```
printf "%s\n" "/node_modules" ".DS_Store" ".env" >> .gitignore
```